# Parsing Javascript (not JSON) in PHP

Tags: php, javascript

I have a php string containing the serialization of a javascript object :

```
$string = '{fu:"bar",baz:["bat"]}';
```

The actual string is far more complicated, of course, but still well-formed javascript. This is not standard JSON, so json_decode fails. Do you know any php library that would parse this string and return a php associative array ?

Comment: Please explain why you can't JSONify it. That would simplify everything a whole lot.

Comment: As said, this is *not* valid JSON. Valid JSON requires objects keys to be formated like strings, ie enclosed with double quotes.

Comment: Yes, I got that. I was asking why can't you make it into valid json in js?

Comment: I was replying to a now-deleted comment.
I can't make a valid string because I'm not making the string. Someone else does.

Comment: I think you should tell that someone that his API is broken

Comment: It's not an API. I'm parsing valid javascript content for my own php purposes.

Comment: If this strijng is not standart, how do you expect a parsing library to exist?

Comment: It's not standard JSON, but it's standard Javascript. Hence the title of my question.

Comment: 8 comments to get to something that was already obvious. Well done :D

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Pear [Services_JSON](http://pear.php.net/pepr/pepr-proposal-show.php?id=198) will parse that string (tested version 1.31). But given that that is a JSON parser and that this isn't valid JSON you have no guarantee that future versions will still work.

Answer (score 20):

This sounded like a fun challenge, so I coded up a tiny parser :D

```
class JsParserException extends Exception {}
function parse_jsobj($str, &$data) {
    $str = trim($str);
    if(strlen($str) < 1) return;

    if($str{0} != '{') {
        throw new JsParserException('The given string is not a JS object');
    }
    $str = substr($str, 1);

    /* While we have data, and it's not the end of this dict (the comma is needed for nested dicts) */
    while(strlen($str) && $str{0} != '}' && $str{0} != ',') { 
        /* find the key */
        if($str{0} == "'" || $str{0} == '"') {
            /* quoted key */
            list($str, $key) = parse_jsdata($str, ':');
        } else {
            $match = null;
            /* unquoted key */
            if(!preg_match('/^\s*[a-zA-z_][a-zA-Z_\d]*\s*:/', $str, $match)) {
            throw new JsParserException('Invalid key ("'.$str.'")');
            }   
            $key = $match[0];
            $str = substr($str, strlen($key));
            $key = trim(substr($key, 0, -1)); /* discard the ':' */
        }

        list($str, $data[$key]) = parse_jsdata($str, '}');
    }
    "Finshed dict. Str: '$str'\n";
    return substr($str, 1);
}

function comma_or_term_pos($str, $term) {
    $cpos = strpos($str, ',');
    $tpos = strpos($str, $term);
    if($cpos === false && $tpos === false) {
        throw new JsParserException('unterminated dict or array');
    } else if($cpos === false) {
        return $tpos;
    } else if($tpos === false) {
        return $cpos;
    }
    return min($tpos, $cpos);
}

function parse_jsdata($str, $term="}") {
    $str = trim($str);


    if(is_numeric($str{0}."0")) {
        /* a number (int or float) */
        $newpos = comma_or_term_pos($str, $term);
        $num = trim(substr($str, 0, $newpos));
        $str = substr($str, $newpos+1); /* discard num and comma */
        if(!is_numeric($num)) {
            throw new JsParserException('OOPSIE while parsing number: "'.$num.'"');
        }
        return array(trim($str), $num+0);
    } else if($str{0} == '"' || $str{0} == "'") {
        /* string */
        $q = $str{0};
        $offset = 1;
        do {
            $pos = strpos($str, $q, $offset);
            $offset = $pos;
        } while($str{$pos-1} == '\\'); /* find un-escaped quote */
        $data = substr($str, 1, $pos-1);
        $str = substr($str, $pos);
        $pos = comma_or_term_pos($str, $term);
        $str = substr($str, $pos+1);        
        return array(trim($str), $data);
    } else if($str{0} == '{') {
        /* dict */
        $data = array();
        $str = parse_jsobj($str, $data);
        return array($str, $data);
    } else if($str{0} == '[') {
        /* array */
        $arr = array();
        $str = substr($str, 1);
        while(strlen($str) && $str{0} != $term && $str{0} != ',') {
            $val = null;
            list($str, $val) = parse_jsdata($str, ']');
            $arr[] = $val;
            $str = trim($str);
        }
        $str = trim(substr($str, 1));
        return array($str, $arr);
    } else if(stripos($str, 'true') === 0) {
        /* true */
        $pos = comma_or_term_pos($str, $term);
        $str = substr($str, $pos+1); /* discard terminator */
        return array(trim($str), true);
    } else if(stripos($str, 'false') === 0) {
        /* false */
        $pos = comma_or_term_pos($str, $term);
        $str = substr($str, $pos+1); /* discard terminator */
        return array(trim($str), false);
    } else if(stripos($str, 'null') === 0) {
        /* null */
        $pos = comma_or_term_pos($str, $term);
        $str = substr($str, $pos+1); /* discard terminator */
        return array(trim($str), null);
    } else if(strpos($str, 'undefined') === 0) {
        /* null */
        $pos = comma_or_term_pos($str, $term);
        $str = substr($str, $pos+1); /* discard terminator */
        return array(trim($str), null);
    } else {
        throw new JsParserException('Cannot figure out how to parse "'.$str.'" (term is '.$term.')');
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
$data = '{fu:"bar",baz:["bat"]}';    
$parsed = array();    
parse_jsobj($data, $parsed);    
var_export($parsed);
```

Gives:

```
array (
  'fu' => 'bar',
  'baz' =>
  array (
    0 => 'bat',
  ),
)
```

Tested with these strings:

```
'{fu:"bar",baz:["bat"]}',
'{rec:{rec:{rec:false}}}',
'{foo:[1,2,[3,4]]}',
'{fu:{fu:"bar"},bar:{fu:"bar"}}',
'{"quoted key":[1,2,3]}',
'{und:undefined,"baz":[1,2,"3"]}',
'{arr:["a","b"],"baz":"foo","gar":{"faz":false,t:"2"},f:false}',
```

Comment: It's really really nice. Two remarks : Javascript object keys can be enclosed in simple quotes or doubles quotes (usually if the key is not a valid identifier (eg contains a space)). And undefined is a valid value.

Comment: I guess it won't work if an object is included in the value of another object and strrpos isn't right, eg '{fu:{fu:"bar"},bar:{fu:"bar"}}'

Comment: I think it will now, I've fixed some bugs for dicts in dicts and arrays in arrays. Your test string works now.

Comment: This version handles quoted keys, and converts undefined to null.

Comment: @gnud your code breaks on following javascript object {name:"Andrew", age: "11", toys: { car: [{color:"red", wheel: "1"} ,{color:"white", wheel: "4"}]}, bus: [ {av: "Mug 2013", var: [ {color:"red", wheel: "10"} ,{color:"white", wheel: "34"}], totl: 10,buy: true}]}

Comment: Also, JavaScript object may start with `[` if it is an array at the top level.  E.g., `[5,4,3,'too',"Juan"]`.

Comment: This is nice, but it unfortunately doesn't handle multi-line objects very well.  It seems to think it's done (prematurely) when it hits a `},` alone on a line. And for some reason recursing too far (?) causes it to throw invalid key errors and misalign on quotes and the like? But thanks for the starting point.

Comment: Neat - I love it :D

Comment: When I set `{key:[{id:1,price:1000,commnet:"foo",memo:[]},{id:2,price:2000,memo:[]}]}`, it occurred error. So, I developed a library to solve this issue. All test strings are passed. I hope it is useful for everyone. https://github.com/Osushi/jsobj2php

Answer (score 2):

I found out that the Yii-framework's `CJSON::decode()` function handles Javascript objects as well.

If you're not using Yii, you should be able to just use the [source code](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii/blob/1.1.14/framework/web/helpers/CJSON.php#L323)

Comment: For **encoding** JavaScript objects (and scalar values) check out [CJavaScript](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii/blob/1.1.14/framework/web/helpers/CJavaScript.php) which does great job with encoding.

Answer (score 2):

thank luttkens

the `CJON::decode()` class of the Yii-framework works perfectly !

```
require_once ($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/phplib/CJSON.php");

$json = new CJSON();
$data = $json->decode('{ url : "/jslib/maps/marker/marker_red.png", height : 34, width : 20, anchorIcon : [5,25.5], anchorText : [0,2], }', true);

print_r( $data );
```

result :

```
Array
(
    [url] => /jslib/maps/marker/marker_red.png
    [height] => 34
    [width] => 20
    [anchorIcon] => Array
        (
            [0] => 5
            [1] => 25.5
        )

    [anchorText] => Array
        (
            [0] => 0
            [1] => 2
        )

)
```

Answer (score 0):

What about that library? 
http://timwhitlock.info/tag/jparser/

I haven't tried it yet.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simplest way to do this:

```php
<?php

function jsObjectToJSON($objstring)
{
    $objstring = preg_replace('/(\w+):/i', '"$1":', $objstring); // replace key with "key"
    $objstring = preg_replace('/\'/i', '"', $objstring); // replace ' with "
    return $objstring;
}

// usage
$objstring = '{foo: "bar", baz: "qux"}';
$json = jsObjectToJSON($objstring);
echo $json; // {"foo": "bar", "baz": "qux"}

// now you can use json_decode() on the result
var_dump(json_decode($json, true));
// array(2) {
//   ["foo"]=>
//   string(3) "bar"
//   ["baz"]=>
//   string(3) "qux"
// }
```

Answer (score 0):

PHP **does not design** for Parsing (Complicate) Javascript String, which contains function, variable, syntax, etc ...
You should use **Browser** for this task. And we have [chrome-php](https://github.com/chrome-php/chrome) with chrome headless mode.
Install it, and use something like this.

```
$evaluation = $page->callFunction(
   "function(a, b) {\n    window.foo = '{fu:\"bar\",baz:[\"bat\"]}';\n}",
   [1, 2]
);

$value = $evaluation->getReturnValue();
```