# Strange Javascript structure

Tags: php, javascript, arrays, parsing

I'm trying to get information from a website through parsing, and I've found this piece of javascript code:

```
var product = {
    identifier: '198980',
    valid: '1378159199',
    fn: 'Entrada para IMAX Barcelona, para cualquier sesión y día',
    description: '',
    category : [ 'Barcelona','Planes del día','Actividades'],
    brand: '',
    price: '5.00',
    amount: '9.75',
    currency: 'EUR',
    url: 'http://es.letsbonus.com/ocio/barcelona/entrada-a-imax-port-vell-2013-08-02-198980',
    photo: 'http://media5.letsbonus.com/products/198000/198980/13509238959102-0-680x276.jpg'
};
```

As you can see, this javascript code contains a lot of information of a certain product in the website, so it would be interesting to get it parsed. I can see that this is not a JSON object, neither a Javascript Array.

*My question is:*

Is this a certain type of Javascript Object? And, if so, is there any easy handling of it in PHP? I'm already able to retrieve this certain string in my code.

Comment: It's a JavaScript object literal.

Comment: it's a javascript object. if you're getting that as text, the quick/dirty/dangerous hack is to simply `eval()` it.

Comment: I'm guessing the main difference in your eyes is the lack of quotation marks on the keys? In JS code (and possibly some definitions of JSON) those can be skipped. There might be some JSON parsers that could handle it if you can skip the "var product = ", but I'm afraid I wouldn't know of any.

Comment: @Katana314 There is only one definition of JSON, and the quotes around the keys are mandatory.

Comment: @bfavaretto Alright, then by "some definitions" I suppose I mean "loose, misinterpretted definitions". Just like most browsers will parse badly-formatted HTML with missing tags.

Comment: I won't use `eval()` because It's too dangerous. And I tried using `json_decode()` in PHP (before realizing the lack of quotation marks) and it didn't work, and then I saw why.

Comment: @markmb I'm pretty sure no one was suggesting you use eval(). I think it may turn out the best way to parse this would be with regex (possibly made easier by the fact that it's spread on multiple lines)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is this a certain type of Javascript Object?

As other have already commented, it's a [JavaScript object literal <sup>*MDN*</sup>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Values,_variables,_and_literals#Object_literals).

> And, if so, is there any easy handling of it in PHP? I'm already able to retrieve this certain string in my code.

Well yes, there is some easy handling. The string you've got is pretty close to JSON, UTF-8 encoded and not especially escaped nor deeply nested.

So you can run some [regular expression based search and replaces <sup>*Docs*</sup>](http://php.net/preg_replace) and then just [`json_decode`<sup>*Docs*</sup>](http://php.net/json_decode) it and if that returns `NULL` you found an error, otherwise you have most certainly your result:

```
$buffer = <<<BUFFER
var product = {
    identifier: '198980',
    valid: '1378159199',
    fn: 'Entrada para IMAX Barcelona, para cualquier sesión y día',
    description: '',
    category : [ 'Barcelona','Planes del día','Actividades'],
    brand: '',
    price: '5.00',
    amount: '9.75',
    currency: 'EUR',
    url: 'http://es.letsbonus.com/ocio/barcelona/entrada-a-imax-port-vell-2013-08-02-198980',
    photo: 'http://media5.letsbonus.com/products/198000/198980/13509238959102-0-680x276.jpg'
};
BUFFER;

print_r(
    json_decode(
        preg_replace(
            [
                '/^\R?var product = ({.*});\R?$/s',
                '/\'([^\']*+)\'/',
                '/^( {4})([a-z]+)\s*:/m',
            ],
            ['$1', '"$1"', '$1"$2":'], $buffer
        )
    )
);
```

Output ([Demo](https://eval.in/44099)):

```
stdClass Object
(
    [identifier] => 198980
    [valid] => 1378159199
    [fn] => Entrada para IMAX Barcelona, para cualquier sesión y día
    [description] => 
    [category] => Array
        (
            [0] => Barcelona
            [1] => Planes del día
            [2] => Actividades
        )

    [brand] => 
    [price] => 5.00
    [amount] => 9.75
    [currency] => EUR
    [url] => http://es.letsbonus.com/ocio/barcelona/entrada-a-imax-port-vell-2013-08-02-198980
    [photo] => http://media5.letsbonus.com/products/198000/198980/13509238959102-0-680x276.jpg
)
```

Answer (score 5):

It's a JavaScript object literal.

If you're fetching this directly from PHP, you'll have to parse it yourself (maybe using regular expressions will be enough). I suggest you also check the following links:

- https://github.com/kbjr/UglifyJS.php/blob/master/javascript-parser.php
- [Parsing Javascript (not JSON) in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1554100/parsing-javascript-not-json-in-php)

Answer (score 1):

That's a [JavaScript object literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Values,_variables,_and_literals#Object_literals). JSON is based on this structured data style.

If you got a handle on this data from JavaScript, just transform it in a JSON string: `JSON.stringify(product);`

From PHP, just transmit it via JSON and decode it with [`json_decode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)

If you only got this script file as text. Then, you'll need to google around, but the idea would be to parse the AST, select the piece you want, `eval` it (in a hopefully secure way) and use it as it, or `JSON.stringify` the result back to PHP.

Comment: I'm directly in PHP, so I cannot use `JSON.stringify(product)`. And using `eval` directly is too much dangerous, so I'll have to process it through a regular expression, as bfavaretto suggested.

Comment: If you feel like it, but the truth is you cannot seriously parse source code via RegExp; they're not enough powerful. After that, saying eval is dangerous is a little diminishing. Everything you do when you program can be dangerous or lead to security leak, the idea is to be responsible.

Comment: But if I'm using `eval` over a chunk of data I got through cURL from another website, this can be very useful and helpful, but I'd prefer to avoid that leak.

Comment: No one can parse arbitrary source code. But if the source is uniform and it has a regular pattern all the time you can use regex. OP should not parse all js codes. He already grabbed this part. The grabbed part is in regular form. So RegExp is just fine