# Parsing data from javascript array by PHP

Tags: php, parsing

I'm working on pricing script which uses data from local comparison shopping engine called zbozi.cz and I would like to ask you about how to get prices (and more) from it. However it returns me HTML file with javascript - and in the javascript codes there are needed data.

For example - I have a PHP array with data like this - http://pastebin.com/BjBtYMv4 - and there are about 10-20 codes like this in the array.

What do I need? Any library or something?
I need to "translate" those javascript data into PHP array and after I'll save it into the MySQL database and process it with another script. It should be really fast because I need to process about 80 000 codes like this a day.

BTW - sometimes there are more / less whitespaces in this code, so the solution should be able to process everything.

Hope I have described my problem enough (my English restriction).

EDIT: I found this - [Parsing Javascript (not JSON) in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1554100/parsing-javascript-not-json-in-php) - but it doesn't work for me :(

EDIT2: It works until "clickthruData" appear, so just one question - could you please make script which edit the code from paste bin to work with script in the EDIT above?

Comment: "I have an PHP array with data like this - http://pastebin.com/BjBtYMv4" - You one you linked is a JavaScript array mind you! Also, it's 100% JSONP encoding you'll need. Most modern browsers have encoding/decoding functions where libraries are not needed like the one you posted (2009).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Javascript you have posted looks like a JSON variable.
Assuming you could cut off everything before an opening curly bracket `{` and a closing curly bracket `}`, you should be able to use [PHP JSON functions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.json.php) to handle this.

Comment: Thus, `JSON_ERROR_SYNTAX` - gotta workout if you have escaped quotes somewhere etc

Comment: I think the `{label: 'item_featured', productName:` is where it's failing, `label` and `poductName` haven't got quotes around them, they **must** do.

Comment: hehe, i've got it! used http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1554100/parsing-javascript-not-json-in-php and edited my string with `$data = str_replace('},', ',', $data);` =)

Comment: Coolio =) Good luck with the rest!

Comment: thank you man, I'm new to stackoverflow should I mark your answer as accepted? It's not the solution, but you helped me.

Comment: If you feel that it helped, you can accept it. The objective is to help get questions answered.

Comment: thank you both guys anyway, I maked your answer because those comments are useful, have a nice week :)

Answer (score 0):

```
var opt = {'id': 'itemRow-0', 
           'url': 'http://www.videotech.cz/audio-video/dj-technika/.../', 
           'cp': '5B9DN0UD-qzuhuuvvKKZjg==' };

var encodedOpt = JSON.stringify( opt );
```

Then within your PHP file that was sent with the variable of encodedOpt,

```
<?php
   $decodedJson = json_decode( encodedOpt );
?>
```

Comment: I forgot to tell you it should work in the CLI mode. So I can't use JS.