# Find only THIS part of the string PHP

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I have a variable $string with the following layout inside :

```
image: "http://web.com/files/images/442873_large.jpg",
thumb: "http://static.web.com/scripts/image.php/60x60/402813.jpg",
mp3: "http://web.com/files/clip/6240/23121376.mp3",
waveform: "http://web.com/files/wave/23121376-wf.png"
```

How could I locate and set the url of thumb: to a new variable ie:

```
$thumb = 'http://static.web.com/scripts/image.php/44x44/442873.jpg';
```

BUT the thumb url (and all of the values) will be different every time the script is run (so I can't match the contents of the actual url).

Basically what function / functions do I need to use to :

1) search the entire string for thumb:

2) select everything in between the directly following quotation marks

3) store the result to a variable (without the "")

Comment: `http://static.web.com/scripts/image.php/44x44/442873.jpg` != `http://static.web.com/scripts/image.php/60x60/402813.jpg`, where does that come from? Have you tried any regex yet (if the data isn't there regex cant be used)?

Comment: But I will never know that value so I can't search for it.

Comment: Is that your actual output? If it's in json e.g. has quotes around image, thumb, mp3, waveform then you can easily `json_decode`

Comment: How is `$thumb` suppose to be assigned? The value you've shown is not in your string..or is it some strange mix of `thumb` and `image` values?

Comment: Bro I have been trying all day to use json_decode and it's driven me crazy. It's actually imported from an XML file, and nothing I tried to make it work simplexml worked at all. I'm at my wits end which is why I'm trying to bumble through it with regex :(

Comment: Don't use regex. Post your simplexml attempts, the real data, and what you need from it.

Comment: Ok will do, you asked for it lol ;)

Comment: @chris85 ok I've seen the problem, the XML I'm using isn't formatted for what I'm trying to do. I have to try a different approach but I'll leave this question here as I'm sure it is something that could be answered and help somebody else. (Find this word, find next " match data until the next "). Thanks for your help

Comment: The question in its current form is unanswerable. If this is a regex question then how do you end up with `http://static.web.com/scripts/image.php/44x44/442873.jpg`, from your current `$string`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102297/discussion-between-chris85-and-grant).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if this is part of a structured data format (json, xml) then you would be better off using a parser for said format.

Failing that, given the information actually provided, a simple regex will do:

```
$string = 'image: "http://web.com/files/images/442873_large.jpg",
thumb: "http://static.web.com/scripts/image.php/60x60/402813.jpg",
mp3: "http://web.com/files/clip/6240/23121376.mp3",
waveform: "http://web.com/files/wave/23121376-wf.png"';

preg_match("~thumb: \"(.*)\",~", $string, $matches);

echo $matches[1];
```

Comment: Yep this does the job. The trouble is the XML file isn't indexed properly so I can't use standard encode / decode functions on it. It won't even let me traverse it as a simpleXML object. This is the only way around it so thank you for saving the day ;)

Comment: @Grant glad i could help. But now im intrigued. could you post a pastebin of the xml file - it might not be as fubar'd as you think

Comment: sure here you go - http://pastebin.com/AReiX0t2 - if you can show me a way to make this work you will be my hero!

Comment: ah yes, i see the problem. the cdata block contains a javascipt object, not json (the properties are not quoted). i would stick to the above regex if i could not change the code that generates the xml

Comment: further reading: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1554100/parsing-javascript-not-json-in-php i would still stick to regex if you just want this simple value

Comment: is it possible to grab the artist: value with regex?

Answer (score 0):

This answer is admittedly rather ugly, but it does work.  It makes use of a couple [explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php)s (to break apart the string), a [foreach](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) (to iterate through the parts), and an [str_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) (to get rid of the double-quotes.

```
$string = 'image: "http://web.com/files/images/442873_large.jpg",
thumb: "http://static.web.com/scripts/image.php/60x60/402813.jpg",
mp3: "http://web.com/files/clip/6240/23121376.mp3",
waveform: "http://web.com/files/wave/23121376-wf.png"';

$array = explode(",\r\n", $string);

$value = "not found";

foreach($array as $entry)
{
    if(substr($entry, 0, 5) == "thumb")
    {
        $parts = explode(": ", $entry);
        $value = str_replace('"', '', $parts[1]);
        break;
    }
}

echo $value;
```