# Search key pair Array to return the Value NOT the Key PHP

Tags: php, arrays, search

I'm not sure if I've titled this correctly...

I have this array :

```
array (
        'fu' => 'bar',
        'baz' =>
             array (
                 0 => 'bat',
             ),
)
```

And I can search it using :

```
echo array_search('bar', $myarray);
```

Which will return the key of bar, which is :

```
fu
```

But how do I search for the value of fu?

If I try :

```
echo array_search('fu', $myarray);
```

I get no results.

!!EDIT to show more code as requested!!

```
$data = '{fu:"bar",baz:["bat"]}';    
$parsed = array();    
parse_jsobj($data, $parsed);
```

Now if I use :

```
var_export($parsed);
```

I get :

```
array (
        'fu' => 'bar',
        'baz' =>
             array (
                 0 => 'bat',
             ),
)
```

If I use this instead :

```
print_r($parsed);
```

I get :

```
Array ( [fu] => bar [baz] => Array ( [0] => bat ) )
```

And I'm trying to return the Value of fu like this :

```
echo array_search('fu', $parsed);
```

But I get no results.

Like wise if I try :

```
echo $parsed['fu'];
echo $parsed[0]->fu;
echo $parsed[0];
```

This function only seems to return the Key and won't return the Value. Maybe I'm looking for a different function?

The class I'm using is [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1554100/parsing-javascript-not-json-in-php)

Comment: `{fu:"bar",baz:["bat"]}` are you sure this is the json string? it ain't valid, the `fu` and `baz` are missing the quotations

Comment: @Ghost That is why he's using the linked class; it's supposed to parse invalid json.

Comment: @RichardTheobald if you already have the final array produced by that class, should be fairly straightforward, just treat it like a normal array

Comment: @Ghost he has the final array, but unfortunately it is an invalid named array. See the `print_r` he posted; no quotes around fu or baz, hence those couldn't be called by name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
echo $myarray[array_search('bar', $myarray)];
```

I'm not sure why you'd want to do this though, as you already know the result of fu. I think it far more likely you actually want to do this:

```
echo $myarray['fu'];
```

edit:
Leaving the above for posterity. After the edit with more info, hopefully this will work:

```
$parsed2 = $parsed;
$parsed = array();
foreach($parsed2 as $key=>$value){
    if(is_string($key) || is_numeric($key)) {
        $parsed[$key] = $value;
    } else {
        $parsed["'".$key."'"] = $value;
    }
}
unset($parsed2);
echo $parsed['fu'];
```

if that doesn't work, then I've no more ideas.

Comment: I've tried both of those ways but it's not working. I'm using this class here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1554100/parsing-javascript-not-json-in-php to convert a javascript array without key pairs into a php readable array. And no, I actually won't know the result of fu in the real world.

Comment: run `var_dump($myarray);` and make sure the array is showing what you expect it to

Comment: The dump is the array that I posted in the question

Comment: Please edit the question and add a larger code sample, then.

Comment: See, that's why I asked for a var_dump. var_export creates valid php code whereas var_dump (and print_r) just spits out what you've got. And what you've got is an invalid named array (note the lack of quotes around fu on the print_r). In order to return it, you're going to have to do a foreach on the array and make it valid first. I'll update my answer.

Comment: Ahh I didn't notice that!

Comment: Yep that did it ;) Thank you, I would have never found that solution by myself!