# Response from api seems to be a string - how to iterate it?

Tags: php, api

I'm receiving data from a webservice in this format - yes, the variable `var visual` is included:

```
var visual = {
    "status": "ok",
    "cached": "1",
    "cache_time": "1674481162",
    "photos": [{
        "photo_id": "81517195",
        "title": "title 1"
    }, {
        "photo_id": "79383391",
        "title": "Title 2"
    }]
}
```

See the [response here](http://video.twentythree.com/api/photo/list?format=json). I guess it's not valid json - I seem to receive it as a string. How can I convert it into json so that I can iterate over each "`photos`" node with php?

Comment: `var visual` is not PHP code, looks like javascript? So where is this data received? And where are you actually trying to process it??

Comment: The json appears valid! You can check yourself at `http://jsonlint.com`

Comment: This is the response I get when requesting a webservice in php.
It's not valid json because it's inside a variable `visual`.

So my question is how I can access the nodes in this response in php. I hope my question makes sense.

Comment: The function in PHP is [json_decode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php). I suggest you check the documentation of the webservice for different options/format, maybe JS is their default and you need to precise it for JSON. If you have no choice you still can strip the `var visual = ` from the beginning of the string

Comment: Are you saying that you get that Whole example you give us INCLUDING the `var visual =`? returned from the webservice

Comment: What web service is this?

Comment: If you receive `{"status": "ok","cached": "1","cache_time": "1674481162","photos": [{"photo_id": "81517195","title": "title 1"}, {"photo_id": "79383391","title": "Title 2"}]}` its valid JSON if you are also receiving the `var visual =` as part of the webservice reply then its obviously not JSON. **Please clarify EXACTLY what you get from the webservice.**

Comment: I'm receiving what I say - it's including the variable - see: http://video.twentythree.com/api/photo/list?format=json

Comment: Stack overflow is not a site to ask question on opinions. "How do I accomplish what I want to do?" You have already identified that the response you get is not json. That's good. Now you need to either show your code and ask what is wrong with it, or we cannot answer what is wrong about your code. If you're wondering how to parse javascript, perhaps [something like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1554100/parsing-javascript-not-json-in-php) may solve your needs.

Comment: You should complain to the support people for that site. This is JavaScript source code, not JSON. There's no good reason why an API should return data like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the php function [json_decode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php). Even tough your code looks like it was written in javascript, if you had the same code as a PHP variable called as **$visual** (with it containing the string, as you mentioned), the solution would look something like this:

```
$visual = "...";  // the response in string format
$decodedJSON = json_decode($visual, true)  // $decodedJSON will contain the provided json in an associative array (specified by the second param)
$firstPhoto = $decodedJSON["photos"][0];  // getting the first photo
```

You can find more information in the [documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php).

EDIT: as @MerlinDenker mentioned above, if you get the `var visual = ...` with your response, then you just have to remove it from the beginning of your response (it can be done using [substr()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php) for example), and then pass it to the [json_decode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) as a string.

Comment: Something tells me its not that simple

Comment: I mean, if what he said is right, and he receives the JSON in string format, then the solution in php would look something like above, but given the fact that he posted possibly JS code, nothing is fix.. :DD

Comment: I think what he is trying to say is he receives the whole string including ``var visual = `` as response from the API. Thus he would just have to remove that at the beginning and then run the remaining JSON code through json_decode as presented in this answer.

Comment: @MerlinDenker you might have 'decoded' his question, if thats the case, then you are certainly right! I'll edit my answer according to this.

Comment: I'm receiving what I say - it's including the variable - see: http://video.twentythree.com/api/photo/list?format=json

Comment: @Meek then the only option you can do is what I mentioned in my edit in my answer. If it was helpful, or if it solved your problem, don't forget to mark it as a solution.:)

Comment: @BorsodiGerii I really appreciate your answer, the only useful input I got in this question. Thank you.

Comment: @Meek no problems:)